# SQL Server: select value, split on a delimiter, then update two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 database table with three varchar Columns - `Col1, Col2, Col3`.  `Col1` has data in it with a single space in between, `Col2` and `Col3` are empty.

I need to write a query to select the data from `Col1`, break up each value using the space as the delimiter, and inserting the data on either side of the space into `Col2` and `Col3` respectively.

I am not too sure how to proceed. Can this be accomplished in SQL, or should I create a small program to do the work for me? I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction if this can be accomplished via SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET 
  Col2 = SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Col1)-1), 
  Col3 = SUBSTRING(Col1, CHARINDEX(' ', Col1)+1, 8000)
WHERE Col1 LIKE '% %';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee there is only one space:

```
create table #temp (col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50), col3 varchar(50))

insert into #temp (col1)
select 'test 1'
union all
select 'test 2'
union all 
select 'test 3'

update #temp
set col2 = left(col1, charindex (' ', col1)),
col3 = substring(col1,charindex (' ', col1)+1, len(col1))
from #temp
```

Comment: ,col3 = substring(col1,charindex (' ', col1) + 1, len(col1))